# How to deploy a contract with inputs by using JSON-RPC?

Tags: json-rpc, contract-deployment

I can deploy a simple contract without any input by using JSON-RPC, like:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"from":"sender's address","code":"compiled contract"}],"id":67}' localhost:8545
```

However, I have no idea how to deploy other contracts which has inputs. 
Could you please show me a demo how to deploy a contract which has inputs by using JSON-RPC? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you mean constructor?